# Not getting refresh token in YouTube OAuth

Tags: oauth, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am doing server side OAuth following [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) guide.

I successfully completed the OAuth, but am not getting a `refresh_token` in the step *Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens*:

**Request:**

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
HOST: accounts.google.com
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length: 260

code=4/KEOuzih9jwfnHj7Rl1DeqHhcJF0goKPwtwR5IQ09ieg&
client_id=****.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=****&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2FsSignIn.html&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "access_token" : "****",
  "expires_in" : 3580,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Two things needed to be done:

1. To get refresh token, you have to pass `access_type=offline` as query parameter to the oauth start request. This will make sure you get the refresh token when doing the oauth for the first time for the account.
2. To get the refresh token on doing the oauth again and again for the same account, you have to pass `prompt=consent` as query parameter to the oauth start request.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: Thanks Abhishek! I was passing the access_type offline but I did not have the prompt consent enabled. Now it returns the refresh token .

Answer (score 1):

The support documents on this is really bad and incomplete.

This is the php code. But these setting produce a Refresh Token.

```
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```